# Can a 12x142 rear hub and 15mm front hub be converted to 9mm quick release with an adapter?

Tags: mountain-bike, wheels, conversion, quick-release, through-axle

I need to replace a pair of 26er mtb wheels and want to see if my qr fork and frame can be adapted for through axle hubs.

Comment: The question is not 'can I', its 'should I'.  Thru axles came with improved frame geometry, engineering and materials. The benefits are often wildly overstated as the axle is the only visible, outward difference between the old and vastly superior new model, so the benefit is put down to the one visible thing.  An old bike is still and old bike, and you can get into all sorts of compatibility problems trying to shoehorn new stuff onto it with an end result worse than what you started with.  Often (usually/always?) better to sell the bike and buy a better one

Answer (score 2):

YES. 
You will need a adaptors called "end caps" that fit the ends of the axle (front&rear) and make it compatible with the use of QR. Depending on the brand of the hubs, the "end caps" can be found on the market - otherwise will need to make it at a turnery (it's a simple work).
But there are exceptions! Some front hubs of type "Boost" are 15mm but slightly wider (110mm vs. 100mm) than traditional QR and 15mm hubs. If the wheels you buy come with this hub, it will not works even using "end caps". 
Before buying future wheels, make sure there are available in the market "end caps" for them.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, as the above answer has explained a some 15mm TA front hubs can be converted to use a 9mm QR.

But...

No, a rear 142x12 TA hub cannot be coverted to fit in a 135x10 frame as there is a 7mm width difference.

Also you ask if your frame or fork can be converted and the answer to that is also no. The open ended dropouts do not have a simple (and safe) solution for through axle conversion.

Comment: The 142x12 hubs are exact same width as 135mm QR, the difference is in axle end cap.

Comment: I guess you're technically correct if you're buying a convertible hub! I'll have to admit I didn't consider that......